# React Router routes not working from URL

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a app that has the following routes:

```
export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/restaurant/:id' component={Restaurant}/>
                    <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
```

The routes work within the app fine. For example if i run my live-server command it pops up in http://127.0.0.1:8080/ and runs the route. From there i can click a link and take me to the other routes. However if I try to go there through the url it gives me a "Cannot get/ Route" error.

This is a problem when i try to do form submissions on those routes as the redirect to its self no longer works.

I am using webpack and read there is something to do with it, but found no solutions.

This is my webpack:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/app.jsx', './src/sass/main.scss', './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src",
        filename: 'bundle.min.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // <-- key to reducing React's size
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        })
        // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), //minify everything new
        // webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(), //Merge chunks
    ],
    watch: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }, { // regular css files
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
        }]
    }
};
```

Im not using any servers, this is my first time using routing so i'm pretty confused. Im using live-server to deploy my react app and webpack to build and bundle my scss and jsx etc.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Before integrating react-router you need to configure your fallback url: So if you are serving your app using webpack, add following to your webpack config:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

In a React app, usually you would wrap `<Route />` in `<Router />` so that when the URL changes, `<Router />` will match a branch of its routes, and render their configured components. Do following :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Content extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/restaurant/:id' component={Restaurant}/>
            <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
)}
}
```

Comment: Yeah i have that in my other component which is calling the Content component. I tried with the devServer fallback but im using live-server not webpack dev server, because when i tried using webpack dev server i got cannot get/ error.

Answer (score 0):

For dev environment you need to set up [webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server) which handle your routes to react, install it to your dependencies.

Then in `package.json` `scripts` section start script should looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --watch"
}
```

Then in root of webpack configuration object set up devServer:

```
devServer: {
  hot: true,
  contentBase: './',
  historyApiFallback: true
},
```

For production you need to write your own `ssr` or use any ssr libraries like [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/)

Comment: This didn't work, when i ran the server even my index page wasn't being shown with this command. my director is like this:
node_module
webpack.js
src

and in src is my index.html and index.js and bundle.min.js which webpack creates. Im not sure if that helps

Comment: In index.html you need to include bundle.min.js(it is output from webpack) and then move to localhost:8080 or your custom port

Answer (score 0):

In application like this (only frontend) the issue is that `/any-route` can't be handled by the browser because they doesn't exists so it returns the error you are seeing.

To fix that issue there are options in development tools like `entry-file` in live-server.

According to its description it should do the work.

```
--entry-file=PATH - serve this file (server root relative) in place of missing files (useful for single page apps)
```

Comment: Where do i add this? Can you post an example

Comment: To post a better example, can you update your question showing how you are running your project?

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Content extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/restaurant/:id' component={Restaurant}/>
            <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
)}
}
```

In my opinion, you should use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter. When you have deployed your app, paths are not working in the live server because of BrowserRouter.